# PHP server retriving images from different paths in different envronments

Tags: php, css, angularjs

My Php application contains Angular components.

Angular components are copied to :**/var/www/vhost/testApp/app/webroot/modules/testApp**

Images used by angular components are present in:
**/var/www/vhost/testApp/css/overcast/images**

When running applications from  test of the environments the images(.png) are retrieved from locations **css/overcast/images/** and the applications works fine.

But in staging environment the browser is retrieving few images from **css/overcast/images/** and few images from **app/webroot/modules/testApp/images**. Since the images are not present in Angular directory the applications is displaying broker images.

In the min css file of angular component the images are defined as below.

Browser try's to retrieve below image from **app/webroot/modules/testApp/images** and returns 404 from the server

```css
.modal-header {
    padding: .4em 1em;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: url(images/ui-bg_glass_35_dddddd_1x400.png) repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #ddd;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative
}
```

Below Image is retrieved from **css/overcast/images/** and it works

```css
.button:active {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #999 url(images/ui-bg_inset-hard_75_999999_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff
}
```

Comment: Remember that relative paths in CSS files are relative to the CSS file itself, NOT the page that's including/using the css. If you're using a mix-path environment, then the css paths should probabyl be made site-absolute. `/full/path/to/images/ui-bgetc...`

Comment: Thanks Marc for the reply but the same version of code is working properly in one environment, and in the environment where I had issue it is retrieving few from actual folder and few from relative path. This is a wired behavior.